# Rolling first derivative and second derivative in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, derivative

I'm trying to create a function to find the rolling derivatives (first and second) in Pandas.
I find that `df.diff()` is quite convenient.

I want to find the derivatives with the rolling window value = 40.

For the first derivative,

```
noise = np.random.normal(size=int(1e4))
noise=pd.DataFrame(noise)
first_derivative=noise.diff(periods=40)
```

Is it correct if I use this for the second derivative?

```
second_derivative=noise.diff(periods=40).diff()
```

I'm confused, but if I put `periods=40` again in the second `.diff()` then it would be 40*40 rolling window (for the second derivative).
Thank you!

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: I believe you are confusing differentiation (derivative operation) with difference of elements. Pandas diff() method calculates discrete differences of elements, as you can check in documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html.

Comment: `diff` doesnt give you the derivative, its just the difference from the previous row. `periods` just controls how much the data is shifted by before calculating the difference, so its not really a window size in the way that youre thinking

Answer (score -1):

Pandas is not a mathematical library, and its `diff()` operation just take discrete differences among elements, not derivatives.

In order to take derivatives, I would recommend you to use [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), a nice Python library for symbolic mathematics. Check [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/calculus.html) for further details.

Example:

```
from sympy import *

>> diff(cos(x), x)
-sin(x)
```

Comment: This is nice for symbolic expressions, but won't work for real data.

Comment: It's an array, not an expression!